# this.passthrough() functionality in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli-mirage

I am writing an application in Ember.js and I am also using Ember mirage. I need to make requests to an external server and I am currently trying to set up my config.js file to deal with such requests. Adding this.passthrough() does not work and I still get an error when I try to make my request saying:

"Your Ember app tried to GET 'http://...' but there was no route defined to handle this request. Define a route that matches this path in your mirage/config.js file. Did you forget to add your namespace?

I believe this should be a simple thing to fix, any ideas of what is going wrong?

Comment: This page may be helpful: 
https://github.com/samselikoff/ember-cli-mirage/issues/970
Many users there are discussing the config.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirage helpdoc explaining it detail. [configuration/#passthrough](http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.3.x/configuration/#passthrough)

If you want all requests on the current domain to pass through, simply invoke the method with no arguments:

```
this.passthrough();
```

You can also allow other-origin hosts to passthrough. If you use a fully-qualified domain name, the namespace property will be ignored. Use two * wildcards to match all requests under a path:

```
this.passthrough('http://api.foo.bar/**');
```

Note:Put all passthrough config at the bottom of your config.js file, to give your route handlers precedence.

Comment: thank you, I do currently have this.passthrough(); at the bottom of my config.js file and I am still getting the above error. Is it an issue if I do not have a namespace defined?

Comment: Are you trying to use other domain, then you need to mention fully-qualified domain name like I mentioned in my answer